# Autorotation screen doesn't work after installing Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: gnome, screen, touchscreen, 23.04, display-rotation

Before installing Ubuntu 23.04, on my Lenovo laptop the autorotation property works and the button to enable and disable this property appears on the top right menu. I can rotate the screen and the displays changes accordingly, either 90º or left and right automatically. After the installation of Ubuntu 23.04, and before and after the updates the button doesn't appear on the GNOME menu, and when rotating the screen to 360 degrees nothing appears or the autorotation property is not working. I want autorotation to start working again and the button on the GNOME menu to appear again.

Is there a easy way to fix this, to enable the autorotation of the screen again and to view the autorotation button on the GNOME menu, and/or there will be an update to fix this? Does anyone know why autorotation is not working in Ubuntu 23.04 after installation? This seems to be an easy fix, since this feature is already available before installation, on Ubuntu 23.04, when I used a USB drive to install Ubuntu 23.04.And i have installed Ubuntu at least two times.

Comment: Install `iio-sensor-proxy` with `sudo apt install iio-sensor-proxy`. Reboot. AutoRotate should work.

Comment: i try to install and said the following; iio-sensor-proxy is already the most recent version, anyway i rebbot but everything stay the same, no automatic rotation of the display. Is there another way, and another way to put again the button of auto-rotation on the gnome menu, to enable and disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

After logout from GNOME and login again but now using xorg, autorotation is active and the button on the gnome menu appear again.So i think is a problem with wayland that need to be fix

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. That is not fix but it save the day It is only work for current user.

`$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor "[]"`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem, and turns out there is a GNOME extension to enable auto-rotation for Wayland. This has worked on my Lenovo Yoga for Ubuntu 23.04, and continues to work on Ubuntu 23.10:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5389/screen-rotate/