# Is Ubuntu the only flavor that can autorotate the screen or Display

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, ubuntu-mate, 23.04, display-rotation

I am wondering if any other flavors of ubuntu, like ubuntu mate, kubuntu and so on have auto rotation of the screen property since ubuntu using gnome is not working properly as i asked the question and so far no one reply

i want to use the auto rotation property in my laptop,that is when i rotate the screen to 360º the orientation of display change

And i am using ubuntu 23.04

And here is my previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479768/auto-rotate-screen-doesnt-work-after-installing-ubuntu-23-04)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu isn't the only Linux distribution that can autorotates the screen.

As far as I know, both Fedora and Linux Mint provide this function.

Comment: i have tried fedora, and didnt work, with the latest , i think fedora 38.but didnt try mint