# 3 finger on touchpad to show menu and applications

Tags: gnome, touchpad, multi-touch, 23.04

On fedora 38 and on windows 11 we can scroll up or down with 3 fingers,on the touchpad and the menu is showed and its applications and also to move between desktop areas.If i try to use 3 fingers on the touchpad nothing happens on gnome using ubuntu 23.04

i am not sure if the latest debian already have this feature. i have installed debian but, dont remenber.And didnt have the autorotation option as i described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479768/autorotation-screen-doesnt-work-after-installing-ubuntu-23-04), and later discover that i had to use xorg instead of wayland, to use autorotation on ubuntu 23.04.

so my question is is some bug on my system,and its not working propely, or the 3 finguer gesture will be implemented maybe in a future realese of ubuntu maybe the 23.10, or even it will be an update for ubuntu 23.04 ?